What is the composition of $\theta^2(x,y)$ where $\theta:(x,y)\to (\dfrac{1}{x},\dfrac{y}{x^3})$
I have following maps $\varphi:(x,y) \to (-x,y), \quad \phi:(x,y) \to (x,-y), \quad \theta:(x,y)\to (\dfrac{1}{x},\dfrac{y}{x^3})$.
Apparently, $\varphi^2(x,y)=\varphi(\varphi(x,y))=\varphi(-x,y)=(x,y)$ :: $\varphi$ takes first coordinate to its negative and $y$ is fixed.
$\phi^2(x,y)=(x,y)$ by the exactly the same reason as above.
$\theta^2(x,y)=\theta(\theta(x,y))=\theta(\dfrac{1}{x},\dfrac{y}{x^3})=(x,y)$
According to book $\theta^2(x,y)$ is $(x,y)$ but why? $\theta$ takes first coordinate to its multiplicative inverse and second component is divided by $x^3$ or multiplied by $\dfrac{1}{x^3}$.
I wrote while working alone that $\theta(\dfrac{1}{x},\dfrac{y}{x^3})$ should be $(x,\dfrac{y}{x^3}\dfrac{1}{x^3})$.
Where am I missing?

Here is the result:
\begin{align*}
  \theta(x,y) &= \left(\frac{1}{x}, \frac{y}{x^3}\right) \\
   \textrm{therefore}~
   \theta(\theta(x,y)) &= \left(\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}} \frac{\frac{y}{x^3}}{\frac{1}{x^3}} \right) \\
    &= (x,y)
\end{align*}
You probably got mixed up with your fractions.
